# Codeception, don't print a specific action to report

Tags: php, codeception

In codeception, I want check if an element exist in the page and do another test if the first element exist. I can do that simply :

```
// $I is a AcceptanceTester Object and extends \Codeception\Actor class
try{
    $I->see('.firstElement');
}catch(ElementNotFound $e){
    // do some actions
}
    // do some anothers actions
```

But If I do that, in the report file I can see the line `"I see '.firstElement'"`. I don't want see this test in this report.

My question : How can I call a \Codeception\Actor method quietly ? I just want do a simple DOM element html check and not print this action into the generated report

Comment: are you use WebDriver?

Comment: Yes =) I use Webdriver with chrome (headless or not) browser

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple helper module to check elements existence. It can use [WebDriver](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver) module or [PhpBrowser](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) module to elements finding. For example:

```
class ElementChecker extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function checkExistence($locator)
    {
        $elements = $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_findElements($locator);
        return !empty($elements);
    }
},
```

After it, you should add this helper to your codeception configuration. For example:

```
actor: SomeTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # some modules
        - ElementChecker
```

And new methods will be included in the tester class. You can use them:

```
if ($I->checkExistence('.firstElement')) {
    // some code
}
```

Also, you can read more about helpers in [the official documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers)